# Android rxjava2 Flowable with compositedisposable

Tags: android, rx-java, observable

I have a problem with Flowables and adding them to the compositeDisposables.
I want to switch from an Observable to a Flowable as the operation might emit 1000 or more values. Im somewhat unexperienced with rxjava2 so please forgive me if that question is stupid :)

So far I used the observable like this:

```
 public Observable<String> uploadPictureRx(String path)
    {
        return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<String> e) throws Exception
            {
                Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
                String segment = file.getLastPathSegment();
                UploadTask uploadTask = reference.child("SomeChild").child(segment).putFile(file);


                uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception)
                    {
                        e.onError(exception);
                    }
                }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot)
                    {                           
                        //noinspection VisibleForTests
                        downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                        String url = downloadUrl.getPath();
                        e.onNext(url);
                        e.onComplete();
                    }
                }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot)
                    {
                        //noinspection VisibleForTests
                        long bytes = taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred();
                        String bytesS = String.valueOf(bytes);
                        e.onNext(bytesS);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

and called the method like this:

```
private void uploadPicToFireBaseStorage(String path)
    {
        compositeDisposable.add(storageService.uploadPictureRx(path)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(mainScheduler)
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<String>()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(String s)
                    {
                        String ss = s;
                        System.out.println(ss);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete()
                    {
                        view.displayToast("Picture Upload completed");
                    }
                })
        );
    }
```

This works fine! However when I try to do the same with a Flowable instead of observable it wont compile:

```
public Flowable<String> uploadPictureRx(String path)
    {
        return Flowable.create(new FlowableOnSubscribe<String>()
        {

            @Override
            public void subscribe(FlowableEmitter<String> e) throws Exception
            {
                Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
                String segment = file.getLastPathSegment();
                UploadTask uploadTask = reference.child("somechild").child(segment).putFile(file);    

                uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception)
                    {
                        e.onError(exception);
                    }
                }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot)
                    {                           
                        //noinspection VisibleForTests
                        downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                        String url = downloadUrl.getPath();
                        e.onNext(url);
                        e.onComplete();
                    }
                }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot)
                    {
                        //noinspection VisibleForTests
                        long bytes = taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred();
                        String bytesS = String.valueOf(bytes);
                        e.onNext(bytesS);
                    }
                });
            }
        }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);

    }
```

The Error is:
 Inferred type 'E' for type parameter 'E' is not within its bound; should implement 'org.reactivestreams.Subscriber

My guess is, that Flowable does not implement Disposable and thats why it wont compile. I have no clue if thats true or not, just my best guess so far. 
Or do I have to change subscribeWith() to subscribe()? I dont know what the impact of that change would be.

Anyway suggestions how to make this work and get this Flowable into my compositedisposable is really appreciated.

Thanks guys!

Edit:

Tried to change the DisposableObserver into a Subscriber. But this results in the following Error:
[Compiler Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSFhh.jpg)

Comment: Flowables use Subscription instead of Disposable for the reason of Backpressure. Basically use Subscription.request() method to tell observable how many items I want for that moment.

Comment: show your subscriber code. I guess error is there not your create.

Comment: Thank you for responding! Isnt my subscriber code the code block in the middle? Sorry if this is silly but so far Ive worked mostly with Singles or Completables.

Comment: where's the compile error happen exactly?

Comment: @AlCabone no. your code in middle is for observable. DisposableObserver won't work for Flowables. Use Subscriber instead.

Comment: @ yosriz  The Compiler Error looks like in the Screenshot Ive posted right now. However, the Error message is different of course:  "Inferred type 'E' for type parameter 'E' is not within its bound; should implement 'org.reactivestreams.Subscriber"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flowables use Subscription instead of Disposable for the reason of Backpressure. Basically use Subscription.request() method to tell observable how many items I want for that moment.

Change your code:

```
private void uploadPicToFireBaseStorage(String path)
{
    compositeDisposable.add(storageService.uploadPictureRx(path)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(mainScheduler)
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<String>()
            {

                @Override
                public void onNext(String s)
                {
                    String ss = s;
                    System.out.println(ss);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete()
                {
                    view.displayToast("Picture Upload completed");
                }
            })
    );
}
```

into

```
private void uploadPicToFireBaseStorage(String path)
{
    compositeDisposable.add(storageService.uploadPictureRx(path)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(mainScheduler)
            .subscribeWith(new ResourceSubscriber<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onNext(String s)
                {
                    String ss = s;
                    System.out.println(ss);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete()
                {
                    view.displayToast("Picture Upload completed");
                }
            })
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you Pheonix Wang Ill give that a try and report back!

Comment: Tried that but unfortunately Im getting another Error now. I will update my Question and insert a Screenshot with the Error.

Comment: You can't add subscriber to CompositeDisposable because CompositeDisposable need Disposables not Subscribers.They are different classes. Or you can use ResourceSubscriber with implements disposable aswell. I update my answer

Comment: Thx man! "Or you can use ResourceSubscriber with implements disposable aswell. I update my answer" Your updated version works like a charm so far! You saved my day! RxJava right now is still very hard to grasp for me. Edit: Would upvote your answer but Im not allowed to by stackoverflow! Need more badges. Sorry

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: @AlCabone for not misleading. you could use DisposableSubscriber aswell instead of ResourceSubscriber. The difference between them is you have an add() method for ResourceSubscriber. You can check it here in JavaDoc http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/subscribers/ResourceSubscriber.html#add(io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the clarification! I checked it out and it compiles as well. Now the question arises which one to choose? Is one preferable over the other in my case? Whats the difference? From what I read out of the documentation (I do not understand much of it) they pretty much do the same? Thank you

Answer (score 6):

`Flowable` works according to **pub-sub pattern**, i.e *publisher - subscriber* pattern

whereas ,

`Observable` works according to **observer pattern**

In *pub-sub pattern* there is middle event channel which *holds* the data released by the `publisher` and then the `event channel` *emits* the data and the `subscriber` gets the data in `onNext(...)`.

Whereas, 
In **observer** pattern the `observable` directly emits the data or throws the data directly to the `observer`. **This might create back-pressure.(cause it emits the whole data in one go.)**

So use (`Flowable`)

```
 .subscribeWith(new ResourceSubscriber<>) // in case of flowable
```

Or,

```
 .subscribeWith(new DisposableSubscriber<>)
```

whereas in case of (`observable`) use

```
  .subscribeWith(new ResourceObserver<>)
```